# Connecting Web API to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, sql-server-2014-express

I am new to ASP.NET and I am creating a Web API using sort of code first. I have model class call gender and defined as follow

```
public class Gender
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I decided to create a new folder call `DBContext` and inside will defined all my `DBContext`, so for the gender class I have created `GenderDb` and look like follow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace BackAPI.Models
{
    public class GenderDB : DbContext
    {
       // not define yet
    }
}
```

However I am having an issue however with `DbContext` not being defined, apparently I am supposed to use Entity Framework, however I want to create my database not through Visual Studio, but using SQL Server 2014 Express.

I did add my data connection and can see that I created a table in SQL Server, however how do I fix `DbContext`, if I use EF wouldn't that just create it locally and that not what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework, along with Migrations, will help you here.

I suggest you check out this tutorial: [Code First to a New Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj193542.aspx)

Comment: This is good information the only issues that I have is how would I set my database to be in my SQL SERVER so I can actually see the data in SQL SERVER, also if i created my project first when should i set up my data connection to SQL SERVER, before I create my first model?

Comment: You would change the connection string that you are using in your application (i.e. via the app.config or web.config).  You can set the connection string before or after you have created the model - it's when you perform the migration that it matters.

Comment: Oh k thank you, i though using EF you were force to use local db